# How can I define which fields are searched?

Tags: search

I am trying to adjust the fields that are being searched on the account. For example, when a user searches for an account via the global search, I only want Salesforce to search the Account Name and Parent Account Name fields. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance, Lily

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can filter the results directly but this might help.

After you perform the global search you will end up with your search results. Something like:

[image]

Once you focus in on the Account (Organizations), you will see a **Customize** option in the top right corner:

[image]

An option within Customize is **Filter for all users**. Here you can select the filter fields to include in this search layout.